# Why does Visual Studio 2010 ignore my reference as soon as I build?

Tags: visual-studio

I have a command line app that uses a certain assembly.  The assembly is sitting in the root of the project, and set to "Copy Always."

I add a reference to that assembly, and Visual Studio 2010 is happy -- Intellisense highlights everything correctly, and no errors are reported.

But as soon as I actually build, I get compilation errors like I haven't added the reference, and Intellisense suddenly gives me red squigglies as if the reference was never added.

But the reference is still there.

If I delete the reference and then re-add it, Visual Studio gets happy again, and the red squigglies go away.  Then I build, and the same thing happens again.

So, Visual Studio agrees that the reference is there.  Until I build.  Then it claims its not.  Even though it is.

And this only happens with a specific DLL (NLog, if it matters). Another DLL (HtmlAgilityPack) works fine, and it's set up and configured the exact same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a little search I found a problem with the [.NET client profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668079.aspx). Try looking at that link and see if it resolves the issue.

There's also some posts on it at the [microsoft connect website](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/530107/lose-project-reference-on-build-if-target-frameworks-mismatch) if you're interested in further reading.

Comment: The target framework was set to ".Net Framework 4 Client Profile."  I changed it to ".Net Framework 4" and it worked fine.  No idea why this fixed it, but it did.  Thanks.

Comment: @Deane: Glad to hear this fixed your problem. NLog 1.0 requires classes in `System.Web` that are not part of the Client Profile. If you don't want a dependency on the full Framework, you can switch to NLog 2.0 (which adds support for the Client Profile) or recompile the DLL without the classes that depend on `System.Web`.